# Site column with calculated default works for list, but not for document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, default-value

I have a single-line-of-text site column with a calculated default.  The calculated default works correctly when added to a list.  However, it doesn't work correctly when it is applied to a document library - the field is blank for any new documents created in the library.

The calculated default itself, which attempts to determine the current Australian fiscal year, is as follows:

```
=TEXT(IF(TODAY()>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),7,1),YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())),"0000")
```

Is there a particular reason this might not be working, and are there workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the formula for calculated value?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I've just updated the question with the formula

Comment: OK. Try using simply adding TODAY(), YEAR(TODAY) first. Check if you are getting the values of this in library.

Comment: Also what is the value you are getting in that column when new document is uploaded in library?

Comment: At the moment, I'm calling it an inconsistent bug. I'm getting your formula to work every time in SP 2016. In the first three tests in SP Online I got blanks, then it just started working for all of the files after that. Weird.

Comment: Are you using the Classic UI or the Modern UI? Required check in? Any other options enabled?

Comment: Thanks Mike - interesting indeed!  I tried creating a whole bunch of files to verify if I was getting the same thing, but instead I have found that the default value is only populated when an existing file from my desktop is drag-dropped into the library, or selected with the SharePoint Upload button.  However, it doesn't populate when I create a new document directly from SharePoint using the "New" button.  The library is modern UI (but I've also tried classic), has no checkout required, only major versions, no content approval required.